# Jersey 2 make class/object persist throughout the app

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have following class:

```
package com.crawler.c_api.rest;

import com.crawler.c_api.provider.ResponseCorsFilter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;

public class ApplicationResource extends ResourceConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = null;

    public ServiceXYZ pipeline;

    public ApplicationResource() {
        System.out.println("iansdiansdasdasds");
        // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
        packages("com.crawler.c_api");

        // Register my custom provider - not needed if it's in my.package.
        register(ResponseCorsFilter.class);

        pipeline=new ServiceXYZ();

        //Register stanford
        /*Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);*/

        // Register an instance of LoggingFilter.
        register(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, true));

        // Enable Tracing support.
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }
}
```

I would like to make the variable pipeline persist throughout the app so i can initialize the service once and use it in every other class.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html). It will give you some idea for how to work with dependency injection with Jersey. As an example, you first need to bind the service to the injection framework

```
public ApplicationResource() {
    ...
    register(new AbstractBinder(){
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(pipeline).to(ServiceXYZ.class);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can just inject `ServiceXYZ` into any of your resource classes or providers (like filters).

```
@Path("..")
public class Resource { 
    @Inject
    ServiceXYZ pipeline;

    @GET
    public Response get() {
        pipeline.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The above configuration binds the single (singleton) instance to the framework.

**Extra :-)** Not for your use case, but say for instance you wanted a new instance of the service to be created for each request. You would then need to put it in a request scope.

```
bind(ServiceXYZ.class).to(ServiceXYZ.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
```

Notice the difference in the `bind`. The first one uses the instance, while the second one uses the class. There is no way to bind the instance this way in a request scope, so if you need special initialization, then you would need to use a `Factory`. You can see an example in the link I provided above

Comment: Thanks again :) Seems more complicated then i thought. Will have a look at it later!

Comment: It's really not that complicated. You can just copy and paste the first snippet, then just inject the service with the annotation where ever you need it